# Find largest number in one list and smallest number in another list to index one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to identify the **highest number** in a list and the **lowest number** in a list to index to a cell?

I have a list of players, each player has total number of picks **(highest being best)**,

Currently I'm using:

```
= Large($I$5:$I$26, 1)
```

But now I would like to add a second criteria, maybe

```
=small($M$5:$M$26, 1)
```

The end result I'm looking for is the result to my list of player names:

```
=Index(B$5:B$26,Match(I$33,I$%:I$26,0))
```

I added the image hoping to clarify things, the formula using IF come up with "Loser" every time. Also I was mistaken it does not default to alphabetical order, but to the first name on the list. Since I sort the list based on each weeks wins that changes the winner on past weeks.

Not enough rep points to add image...

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. You say "The End result I'm looking for is the result to my list of player names", which doesn't make much sense. What does your list of players look like, are the players in rows and there are multiple columns with their "Picks" (what is a pick, btw?). There is just too much ambiguity here to answer the question.

Comment: I have a spreadsheet to track a pick pool. Each week I would like a formula to identity the winner. Currently it identifies the winner (highest number of correct picks) but in the event of a tie it list the first name in alphabetical order. I would like it to use a secondary criteria or tie breaker. The tie breaker is a separate list, the lower the number the better.

Answer (score 0):

This webpage might help you -- it discusses `INDEX MATCH MATCH` (matrix lookup) and has pointers to the other available lookup functions.
http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/

If you use `MAX()` and `MIN()` instead of `LARGE(x,1)` and `SMALL(x,1)` it might make your code slightly simpler.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the link here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data starts on Row 5, you could make a new column in the sheet to report which person is the "Winner". The formula would look like:

`=IF(AND(I1=MAX($I$5:$I$26), M1=MIN($M$5:$M$26)), "Winner", "Loser")`

This `IF` statement will test your two conditions (that the line contains the max of `I5:I26` and that the line contains the min of `M5:M26`. If both conditions are true it spits out "Winner", if not it spits out "Loser".

You could make a new `Index(Match())` formula to look up "Winner" and return the name of the person from Column B.